# What are material nodes and composite nodes? And how do they relate to geometry nodes?

Tags: node-editor

I'm a newbie, so pardon my ignorance.

The manual, in the [introduction to nodes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/nodes/introduction.html), lists three types: shader, composite, and texture nodes. It links to documentation of each of the three types.

On the page about node groups, the section [*Make Groups*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/nodes/groups.html#make-group) says, "Blender does not make a distinction between material node groups or composite node groups. So it is recommended to use some naming convention that will allow you to distinguish between the two types." In the documentation of shader nodes, the [page on node groups](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/render/shader_nodes/groups.html) says, "Both material and composite nodes can be grouped."

So we've got documentation of shader, composite, and texture nodes, but then there's this different classification into material and composite nodes, and I don't see any explanation of that.

Does "material nodes" just mean shader nodes and texture nodes?

Aside from all of that, there's [geometry nodes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/index.html), which seem to be something separate from shader, composite, and texture nodes. So where do they fit into the picture? Are they either material and composite nodes, or are they something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oxford Learner's Dictionaries:

1. **node** *(technology) (computing) a point at which two lines or systems meet or cross: a network node*

So first of all, "nodes" can be found in many softwares for many more purposes than just shading or compositing. There are programming languages, video editors, game engines, AI art generators etc. all making use of node-based workflows. They do not (not even within Blender) have to be in any way related to each other, because it simply means you have "nodes" for certain tasks and to build a workflow you connect them with each other to perform some kind of action.

For the separation of geometry nodes from the others in the documentation you have to either ask the developers or just guess like me: for one, geometry nodes are quite new in Blender other than material and compositor nodes, and the documentation is not always (correctly) updated in all parts and two, geometry nodes are much more complex so when they were introduced they probably wanted to give them their own dedicated section to explain them in more detail.

I will concentrate only on material and compositor nodes now to deal with your question what shader and texture nodes are:

**Material nodes** does not mean **only** shader and texture nodes. Like in all node-based workflows in Blender, there also exist all kinds of other nodes like *Math* and *Mix* etc. Also texture nodes are not exclusive to materials, you have them in the compositor and geometry nodes as well. I think the distinction between material nodes and compositor nodes is made because those are two different editors, and although it is not called the *Material Editor* but the *Shader Editor* (because its output is the surface shading information for the render engine), they did not call the general material nodes "shader nodes" to not confuse them with the specific shader nodes which I talk about further down.

A **texture node** holds a texture, which is (often) a 2D map of colors or greyscale values which can either be some form of image or procedurally generated by a function like noise, waves, voronoi etc. Not all procedural textures are 2-dimensional though, depending on the function they can be 3- or 4-dimensional as well.

Now while these texture maps can represent information about color, roughness or height distribution among others, they just provide the pure values - if for example you plug an image texture into a *Material Output* directly, Blender does not know if this image is a base color, a roughness map or a bump map.

That's where **shader nodes** come into play. Shader nodes are exclusive to materials, because they provide information on how to *shade* the surface (for volumes, how to distribute densities). They can either be for specific purposes (like the *Diffuse BSDF*, *Glass BSDF* or *Transparent BSDF*) or a combination of multiple purposes like the *Principled BSDF*.

These shader nodes give the necessary information to the render engine how things like colors, texture maps etc. have to be interpreted to create surface qualities that result in the look of the object when rendered.

I could explain much more in detail and of course these topics are more complex and other people can surely give even better explanations than me, but to be honest, in my opinion this question should be closed for not being focused enough and much too broad. Also a lot of things like what are these nodes etc. you can learn much better if you watch beginner tutorials on these subjects instead and even learning by doing, just using nodes and discovering what they do and so on... just like the most of us did.

Comment: Gordon, thank you for getting in a detailed answer before the question got closed. Like your other answer that I just accepted, I hope I can understand it by the time I finish the donut tutorial. As for learning by doing, yes, I'm not just watching the videos, and also not just building the donut, but demanding of myself that I understand what I'm doing, which is hard. So yes, I guess the question lacked focus because it's hard to focus when one is groping one's way through a fog. Your answer will help as I get more experience with these structures.